# Swing JTable row borders goes away after applying Nimbus LookAndFeel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtable, look-and-feel

I have a java 8 program in which - Parent is a JFrame that has Menu, few buttons, a text field and a JTable with fixed number of non-editable rows.  Number of rows and data cannot be changed dynamically.

Menu has list of `UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()`
Initially JTable rows border are visible
If LookAndFeel change to `[Nimbus javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel]`, and then try any other LookAndFeel, rows border goes away.
I am using `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(parentFrame)` to apply LnF. LnF is applying on all components including JTable, but once Nimbus LnF applied and after that choosing any other LnF, rows border went off.
As a option `repaint()` is not making any difference.

In image

- (1) is when program starts where row borders are visible
- (2) when Nimbus LnF applied
- (3) LnF changed to Metal but row borders are NOT visible

Please suggest.

[image: Application]

Sample Code:

```
package com.sv.runcmd;

import com.sv.core.logger.MyLogger;
import com.sv.swingui.SwingUtils;
import com.sv.swingui.component.AppExitButton;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import static com.sv.core.Constants.SP_DASH_SP;
import static com.sv.swingui.UIConstants.EMPTY_BORDER;

public class LnFExample extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LnFExample().initComponents();
    }

    private static final String APP_TITLE = "LnF";

    private DefaultTableModel model;
    private JTable tblCommands;

    private JMenuBar mbarSettings;

    public LnFExample() {
        super(APP_TITLE);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(this::initComponents);
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes the form.
     */
    private void initComponents() {

        Container parentContainer = getContentPane();
        parentContainer.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JButton btnExit = new AppExitButton(true);
        createTable();

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        topPanel.add(btnExit);
        topPanel.setBorder(EMPTY_BORDER);

        JPanel lowerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JScrollPane jspCmds = new JScrollPane(tblCommands);
        lowerPanel.add(jspCmds);

        parentContainer.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        parentContainer.add(lowerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        btnExit.addActionListener(evt -> exitForm());
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
                exitForm();
            }
        });

        createAppMenu();
        setPosition();
    }

    private final MyLogger logger = MyLogger.createLogger("rc.log");

    private void createAppMenu() {
        mbarSettings = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menuSettings = new JMenu("Settings");
        menuSettings.add(getThemesMenu());
        mbarSettings.add(menuSettings);

        setJMenuBar(mbarSettings);
    }

    public UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo[] getAvailableLAFs() {
        return UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels();
    }

    public JMenu getThemesMenu() {

        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Theme");

        int i = 'a';
        int x = 0;
        for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo l : getAvailableLAFs()) {
            JMenuItem mi = new JMenuItem((char) i + SP_DASH_SP + l.getName());
            if (i <= 'z') {
                mi.setMnemonic(i);
            }
            int finalX = x;
            mi.addActionListener(e -> applyTheme(finalX, l));
            menu.add(mi);
            i++;
            x++;
        }
        return menu;
    }

    UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo themeToApply;

    public void applyTheme(int idx, UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo lnf) {
        themeToApply = lnf;
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(this::applyLnF);
    }

    public void applyLnF() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(themeToApply.getClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
    }

    private void createTable() {
        model = SwingUtils.getTableModel(new String[]{"Col1"});
        createRows();
        Border borderBlue = new LineBorder(Color.BLUE, 1);
        tblCommands = new JTable(model);
    }

    private void createRows() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            model.addRow(new String[]{"Row- " + i});
        }
    }

    private void setPosition() {
        // Setting to right most position
        pack();

        GraphicsConfiguration config = getGraphicsConfiguration();
        Rectangle bounds = config.getBounds();
        Insets insets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(config);

        int x = bounds.x + bounds.width - insets.right - getWidth();
        int y = bounds.y + insets.top + 10;

        setLocation(x, y);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Exit the Application
     */
    private void exitForm() {
        setVisible(false);
        dispose();
        logger.dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: (1-) This question was asked earlier: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65254253/swing-jtable-row-borders-goes-away-after-applying-nimbus-lookandfeel#65254253) and deleted. The suggestion was to provide an [mre]. I still don't see one.

Comment: By the way Ive replicated your issue, when I go from Nimbus to Metal `JTable` row borders are not correctly rendered however other L&Fs this does not happen with and do see this as a potential bug, however please do update with a minimal reproducible example as @camickr has said and perhaps when you show some effort others will too

Comment: @camickr - I deleted earlier one bcoz of same reason to put more information around it.  Let me add code, it would be great if you remove -1 bcoz this is problem is reproduced and might be helpful for others

Comment: As @DavidKroukamp said it might be potential jdk bug I reported to Oracle JDK team.

Comment: @shaILU Yeah definitely seems like a bug, ensure you jave the latest jdk 8 version and if it still appears then wait for Oracle to respond

Comment: I tried latest jdk 8.  Results remain same.  Thanks.

Comment: The downvote was because we should NOT need to repeat ourselves. You were asked in the last question to post an [mre]. Repeating the question without the "MRE" does not improve the question as we can't test an image to see if we get the same results. We don't know if you are using custom renders for example, which can cause an issue. Downvote was removed this time.

Comment: @shaILU, *removed downvote by now* - don't be so worried about down votes and post a proper question the first time. And by the way you still have NOT posted an [mre] (1-). You are still using all kinds of 3rd part classes, so we can't copy/paste/compile and test the code you pasted. There is no need for those classes. It takes a single statement to create a JTable: `new JTable(3, 3);`. The data is irrelevant. Your question is about the borders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in comments and by @camickr, this is probably a bug with *Nimbus* or *Metal LaF*.

However I have made a workaround that you can use for now.

Essentially I override `prepareRenderer` of the `JTable` and check if the Metal LaF is being used ( and that it wasnt set on start up or it will paint 2 borders around the `JTable`) and if those conditions are met we simply set the border for each row to `new MetalBorders.TableHeaderBorder()`:

```
@Override
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
    JComponent component = (JComponent) super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
    if (UIManager.getLookAndFeel().getName().equals("Metal") && !wasMetalOnStartup) {
        component.setBorder(new MetalBorders.TableHeaderBorder());
    }
    return component;
}
```

[image]

**TestApp.java:**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalBorders;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.OceanTheme;
import javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class TestApp {

    private JTable table;
    private boolean wasMetalOnStartup = false;

    public TestApp() {
        setNimbusLookAndFeel();
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(TestApp::new);
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        wasMetalOnStartup = UIManager.getLookAndFeel().getName().equals("Metal");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestApp");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

        // setup chmahe LaF button
        JButton refreshButton = new JButton("Change L&F");
        refreshButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            try {
                if (!UIManager.getLookAndFeel().getName().equals("Nimbus")) {
                    setNimbusLookAndFeel();
                } else {
                    setMetalLookAndFeel();
                }
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        });

        table = new JTable() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
                JComponent component = (JComponent) super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                if (UIManager.getLookAndFeel().getName().equals("Metal") && !wasMetalOnStartup) {
                    component.setBorder(new MetalBorders.TableHeaderBorder());
                }
                return component;
            }

        };

        // setup JTable and custom table model with intial data
        Object[][] data = getRandomData();
        String[] columnNames = {"Random Data"};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        table.setModel(model);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(300);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());

        // add components to the panel
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
        panel.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(refreshButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    private void setNimbusLookAndFeel() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new NimbusLookAndFeel());
            wasMetalOnStartup = false;
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }

    private void setMetalLookAndFeel() {
        try {
            MetalLookAndFeel.setCurrentTheme(new OceanTheme());
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new MetalLookAndFeel());
            wasMetalOnStartup = false;
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }

    private Object[][] getRandomData() {
        Object[][] data = {{UUID.randomUUID()}, {UUID.randomUUID()}, {UUID.randomUUID()}, {UUID.randomUUID()}};
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: (1+) but I would suggest you might be able to use: `UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder")` to reset it for any non-Nimbus LAF.

Comment: Thanks David and @camickr.  It worked for me and I accepted ans.  As this was and both of you might have removed downvote by now, if not please do (I can see still one downvote).  I will keep in mind about MRE.  Thanks to both of you.

Comment: Glad to help. And I never downvoted. I did upvote and retracted my close vote. If mine and @camickrs answers have helped perhaps think about upvoting them too.

Answer (score 3):

I also get the same results using JDK11 on Windows 10.

I suspect the issue is with the `UIResource` interface. Note, this is just a tagging interface, there are no actual methods to implement.

It is my understanding that this interface should be implemented on properties of Swing components. For example on the Font, Border, Color, Icon properties of the various component.

Then when you invoke `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(parentFrame)` all the properties that implement the `UIResource` will be replaced with the respective property from the new LAF.

Check out [UIManager Defaults](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/). It will list all the properties of each Swing component.

You will see that for most LAF's the properties are in instance of `FontUIResource`, or `ColorUIResource`, etc.

However, for the Nimbus LAF many properties lack the "...UIResource".

So I would suggest this is a Nimbus issue and I have no idea how to fix it.

Edit:

> hard to tell while debugging if this was a Metal LaF issue ... or a Nimbus issue

It is a Nimbus issue.

Download the code from the above link and then make the following change:

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI( rootPane );
System.out.println(table.getDefaultRenderer(Object.class));
```

Now toggle the LAF between non NImbus and you will see that the default table renderer for the non Nimbus LAF's contain UIResource in the class name which would indicate to me that they implement the UIResource interface.

Now toggle to the Nimbus LAF. The renderer does not have UIResource in the class name.

Now toggle back to any other LAF and the rendering is incorrect because the Nimbus renderer has not been replaced with the proper LAF renderer.

Note, this is not a LAF issue. It is designed to work this way. This allows you to create a custom renderer that can be used in all LAF (unless of course you tag the renderer with the UIResource interface).

For some reason the Nimbus developers appear to not have tagged the renderers with the UIResource interface so once they are set they are not changed with the rest of the LAF.

So another solution would be to create a "wrapper" renderer that simply wraps a default renderer and invoke its default renderering logic but would also implement the UIResource interface . Then you would need to replace each default Nimbus renderer with a wrapper renderer.

Comment: Nice explanation, though it was hard to tell while debugging if this was a Metal LaF issue i.e. it doesn't replace the table defaults correctly or a Nimbus issue i.e. it does something strange with the table cell renderer ( it uses synthetic LaF for that for that from a look at the source code). I could fix it by simply overriding the `prepareRenderer ` method of the `JTable` and setting the border to `MetalBorders.TableHeaderBorder` but yeah kind of a hack because you would need to keep track of if this was the first time metal was applied or not  or it would double the borders. +1.

Comment: @shaILU Check my answer for a potential work around

Comment: @DavidKroukamp I believe it is a Nimbus (not Metal) issue. See edit.

Comment: Nice one mate!!

Comment: I believe after Nimbus effect affects Windows and WindowsClassic LnF as well, I will modify code accordingly.

Comment: @shaILU, that is what my answer states. Its states that the Nimbus renderers are not replaced. So they would be used by any other LAF you switch to. The proper solution, is to wrap the Nimbus renderers. Overriding the `prepareRender(...)` renderer does not replace the proper renderers for the LAF

Answer (score 1):

Got an email reply to bug I raised from Oracle regarding this issue and they also able to reproduce it as a bug.
JDK-8258567. 
Link : http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8258567